# Behat 3 - Behat\Behat\Context\Step\Given not found

Tags: php, bdd, behat, mink

I'm testing Behat/Mink for the first time with a simple example.
When I launch `behat` I have this error :

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Behat\Behat\Context\Step\Given' not found in /var/www/behat-test/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php on line 31`

**features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php :**

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Step;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext implements Context, SnippetAcceptingContext
{
    // ......

    /**
     * @Given I am logged in as :username
     */
    public function iAmLoggedInAs($username)
    {
        return array(
            new Step\Given('I go to "login.php"'), // line 31
            new Step\When('I fill in "My name" with '.$username),
            new Step\When('I press "Login"')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Behat2, *Given/When/Then* classes were used for **step chaining**. Since this technique brought more **problems** (with maintenance) then benefits, they're **no longer supported in Behat3** (which you apparently use). It's also not recommended to follow this practice.

See https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/546.